# Angular 2 Multiple router params

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Assuming I wish to have the following URL:

```
myurl.com/data/11-20-84-2
```

and each number appears in the url will be a router param I can use from my component.

Is it possible?

The following didn't work:

```
{ path: 'view-score/:score-:number',
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
{ path: 'view-score/:score/:number',
```

Comment: And way to make it possible with another divider than a `slash`? (like `-` I mentioned)

Comment: If you want another divider, than make it only a single parameter and split it in your code yourself when you read the parameters from the router. The router itself doesn't support custom dividers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single parameter:

```
path: 'view-score/:numbers'
```

And then when retriving the parameter in your code, split it yourself like:

```
let numbers = this.route.snapshot.params.numbers;
let numbersArr = numbers.split("-");
let score = numbersArr[0];
```